# failed to calculate median images using parfor

Tags: matlab, parfor

I'm trying to calculate the median image of a series of images.
`tableau4D` corresponds to a time series of images.

```
tableau4D(pixel_x, pixel_y, value_grayscale, time t)
```

I have a lot of images and want to use parfor to increase calculation speed.
But I get an error.

my code :

```
% Calcul mediane serie image
function Io_mediane = median_images(tableau4D)
    %Io_mediane = median(tableau4D, 4);
    % Calcul taille du tableau
    [m,n,c,nombre_images] = size(tableau4D);

    % init temp
    Io_med_temp = zeros(m,n,c,nombre_images);

    parfor i = 1:nombre_images %parfor bug 
        Io_med_temp(:,:,:,i) = medfilt2(tableau4D(:,:,:,i));
    end
    Io_mediane = mean(Io_med_temp,4);
end
```

my error :

```
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'Processes' profile ...
Connected to parallel pool with 20 workers.
Warning: X does not support locale fr_FR.utf8
Error using post>median_images/parfor%supply_3
Out of memory.

Error in post>median_images (line 195)
    parfor i = 1:nombre_images %parfor bug

Error in post (line 33)
Io_mediane = median_images(Io_land);
 
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'Processes' profile ...
Parallel pool using the 'Processes' profile is shutting down.
```

Do you have any advice?
(If I replace parfor by for, It's works)

Comment: Use a thread-based parallel pool. Or configure your parallel pool to have fewer workers.

Comment: `medfilt2` works on 2D images.

Comment: Your title and text say you want to compute the median of a set of images, but then you apply a median filter to each image, which seems to be a different thing

Comment: @Cris' suggestion is a good one. But there's a secret trick that will also be needed to stop exploding memory during `parfor%supply`, and that's to force it to treat `tableau4D` as a broadcast variable, by calling something like `size(tableau4D)` _inside_ the `parfor` loop.

Comment: Ok thanks you. I will try to configure my parallel pool and call size(tableau4D) inside the parfor loop